# How to get the response headers with ajax "PUT" request

Tags: jquery, ajax, response-headers

I am sending ajax 'PUT' request and it is getting success also, but i am not getting anything in response, now without using response data i have get the response headers values, so how can i get those values

```
$.ajax({
          url:url,
          type:"PUT",
          data:blobData,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success:function(data, request, xhr){
            console.log("response headers..", xhr.getResponseHeader());
          },
          error:function(error){
            console.log(error);
          }
        });
```

xhr.getResponseHeader(); this is not giving anything just i am getting empty. but in headers section i can see the Response Headers (which is in developer tool > network), so i except those headers values.

Comment: if you `console.log(xhr)` cant you find the path/ properties on the response headers?

Comment: in response headers section (in network < developer tool) i can see the multiple headers, but 'xhr' response is giving empty result

Comment: im not talking about the network debug, im talking about the console log. if you log xhr and it is empty, something seems to be wrong

Comment: Yeah, xhr is empty.